# Как правильно хранить значения в HashMap, если есть класс конструктор

Tags: java

У меня есть две переменные: `int example` и `String test`  как сделать чтобы  это число `int x` было привязано только к этим двум переменным? (`int example` и `String test`) и как его получить по ним?

Comment: не очень понятно, что вы имеете в виду под "привязыванием" `int x` к другим переменным

Comment: ну как в HashMap есть ключ и его значение тут ключ - int example и String test а значение - int x но в HashMap я не знаю как это положить

Comment: то есть как сделать в HashMap 2 ключа и 1 значение?

Comment: да, как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Не нужно создавать класс Key, как предложено выше, в качестве ключей в Маp рекомендуется использовать примитивы, либо Immutable объект, в предложенном выше варианте ключ не Immutable. Когда вам нужно концептуально объединить несколько полей вы создаете новую сущность - а затем кладете в`Map<Integer, DataEntry>`. где Integer порядковый номер, как я понял в вашем примере он уникален(вместо Integer можно сделать Enum, в Enum создать ключи вида ONE, THO, THREE), а DataEntry следующий класс:

```
class DataEntry{

    private final int example;

    private final String test;

    public DataEntry(int example, String test) {
        this.example = example;
        this.test = test;
    }
    public int getExample() {
        return example;
    }

    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }

}
```

Вариант с самодельным ключом -  необоснованно усложнен, и вы рискуете потерять в нем свои значения, если вдруг самодельный ключ изменит свой hash(изменится любое из полей)

Comment: где же ключ не Immutable в моем варианте? Все поля final. И hash опять же не изменится, потому что поля не поменять. Минусовать не буду, но необоснованные обвинения не нужно вешать, не разбираясь в вопросе.

Comment: А так же ваш ответ неверен с той точки зрения, что вы додумываете требования к задаче, чтобы подогнать их под свое решение ("как я понял, в вашем примере он уникален"). Не известно, уникален ли он, может уникально только сочетание двух, поэтому вопрос был и задан.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы это сделать, сначала нужно сделать класс ключа:

```
public class Key {
    private final int example;
    private final String test;

    public Key(int example, String test) {
        this.example = example;
        this.test = test;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Key)) return false;
        Key key = (Key) o;
        boolean equals = example == key.example;
        if (test != null) {
            equals = equals && test.equals(key.test);
        } else {
            equals = equals && key.test == null;
        }
        return equals;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hashcode = example;
        hashcode = 31 * hashcode + test.hashCode();
        return hashcode;
    }
}
```

Затем, просто при создании `Map`, мы будем указывать тип `Key`:

```
Map<Key, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Хочу еще отметить, что если вы будете дописывать класс `Key`, добавлять в него значения, вам так же надо будет дописать метод `equals()` и, возможно, `hashCode()` (cкорее всего уже необязательно, если будет устраивать производительность, т.к. коллизии hashCode() всё равно возможны и программу не поломают).

Если интересно, можете почитать, как работает `HashMap`.